# Thread that terminates after webservice return executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

My problem is that the web service returns a value of the static variable response in the recognition class before the thread updates its value (not up to date value)
here is my web service :

```
@GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public synchronized  String returnTitle() {
            String result="init value";
            Recognition recognition = new Recognition();
            FutureTask<String> future = new FutureTask(recognition);
            future.run();
            System.out.println("result0 = "+result);
            try{
                System.out.println("result = "+result);
             result = future.get();
             System.out.println("result1 = "+result);
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            return "<h1>hello</h1> "+ Recognition.response;
        }
```

This class contains the static variable called response that well be returned by the web service.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import com.bitsinharmony.recognito.MatchResult;

public class Recognition implements Callable<String>{

public static String response =""; // The variable to return by the web service.


@Override
public  String call() throws Exception {
    response= "";
    if (!Ressources.isInitilalized){ // if the initialization of training data is not done yet. 
        Ressources.init();          // initialize training data
        Ressources.isInitilalized= true; //changing the boolean variable to know that inisialization has been done next execution
    }
        final JavaSoundRecorder recorder = new JavaSoundRecorder(); // Class used to record voice from microphone and save it to .wav file.

                Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() { // Thread that sleeps 5000 ms then stops recording.
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        recorder.finish(); // after timer finished stop recording

                        try{
                            File file20 = new File("C:\\RecordAudio.wav");

                            List<MatchResult<String>> matches = Ressources.recognito.identify(file20);

                            MatchResult<String> match = matches.get(0);
                            //file20.delete();

                            System.out.println(match.getKey() + " " + match.getLikelihoodRatio());


                         response =  match.getKey()+" "+match.getLikelihoodRatio()+"\n";// say for which user the sound recorded belongs with witch probability.
                        }catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                });

                stopper.start(); // start the thread

                // start recording 
                recorder.start(); // start recording

    return response;
}

}
```

This class contains static resources to train the model of speaker identification :

```
import java.io.File;

import com.bitsinharmony.recognito.Recognito;

public class Ressources {
    public static String response = "hello : ";
    public final static File file0 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\silence12.wav");
    public final static File file00 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\noise12.wav");
    public final static File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\dhia12.wav");
    public final static File file30 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\dhia30.wav");
    public final static File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\dhia2.wav");
    public final static File file3 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\obama1.wav");
    public final static File file4 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\obama2.wav");
    public final static File file5 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\obama3.wav");
    public final static File file6 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\reagan1.wav");
    public final static File file7 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\reagan2.wav");
    public final static File file8 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\reagan3.wav");
    public final static File file9 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\georgebush1.wav");
    public final static File file10 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\georgebush2.wav");
    public final static File file11 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\georgebush3.wav");
    public final static File file12 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\georgebush4.wav");
    public final static File file13 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\carter1.wav");
    public final static File file14 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\carter2.wav");
    public final static File file15 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\clinton1.wav");
    public final static File file16 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\clinton2.wav");
    public final static File file17 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\huyan1.wav");
    public final static File file18 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\huyan2.wav");
    public final static File file19 = new File("C:\\Users\\dsghaier\\Desktop\\Records\\huyan3.wav");
    public static Recognito<String> recognito = new Recognito<String>(16000.0f);
    public static boolean isInitilalized = false;
    public static void init(){
        try{
        recognito.createVoicePrint("Dhia", file1);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Dhia", file2);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Dhia", file30);
        recognito.createVoicePrint("Obama", file3);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Obama", file4);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Obama", file5);
        recognito.createVoicePrint("Reagan", file6);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Reagan", file7);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Reagan", file8);
        recognito.createVoicePrint("George Bush", file9);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("George Bush", file10);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("George Bush", file11);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("George Bush", file12);
        recognito.createVoicePrint("Carter", file13);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Carter", file14);
        //recognito.createVoicePrint("Clinton", file15);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Clinton", file16);
        //recognito.createVoicePrint("Huyan", file17);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Huyan", file18);
        //recognito.mergeVoiceSample("Huyan", file19);
        //recognito.createVoicePrint("Silence", file0);
        //recognito.createVoicePrint("Noise", file00);
        // ********************************
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        isInitilalized = true;
        }
}
```

And finally this class is used to record sound and save it into a .wav file :

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * A sample program is to demonstrate how to record sound in Java
 * author: www.codejava.net
 */
public class JavaSoundRecorder {
    // record duration, in milliseconds
    static final long RECORD_TIME = 500;  

    // path of the wav file
    File wavFile = new File("C:/RecordAudio.wav");

    // format of audio file
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    // the line from which audio data is captured
    TargetDataLine line;

    /**
     * Defines an audio format
     */
    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 16000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                             channels, signed, bigEndian);
        return format;
    }

    /**
     * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
     */
    public void start() {
        try {
            AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

            // checks if system supports the data line
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                System.out.println("Line not supported");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();   // start capturing

           // System.out.println("Start capturing...");

            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

         //   System.out.println("Start recording...");

            // start recording
            AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
     */
    public void finish() {
        line.stop();
        line.close();
       // System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

Comment: May we see your current code? It may be hard for readers to understand your problem without seeing what you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just initialize your static variable.
Initializing and declaring a variable is not the same:

- Initializing : `int a = 0;`
- Declaring : `int a;`

If this is not what you are looking for, maybe you might be a bit more specific and show us an error message